# How can i fix the error when installing arpreq in python?

Tags: python

I tried to install `arpreq` for a project in Python but I got this error code and I don't know what to do with it:

```
pip install arpreq
Collecting arpreq

Using cached arpreq-0.3.3.tar.gz (8.4 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: arpreq

Building wheel for arpreq (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\youri\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\youri\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-eabmp7dg\\arpreq\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\youri\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-eabmp7dg\\arpreq\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\youri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-wh7j84nb'
       cwd: C:\Users\youri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-eabmp7dg\arpreq\
  Complete output (13 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'arpreq' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\youri\anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\youri\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/arpreq.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/arpreq.obj -std=c99
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c99'
  arpreq.c
  src/arpreq.c(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/socket.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ERROR: Failed building wheel for arpreq
  Running setup.py clean for arpreq
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arpreq does not run on Windows, just the Unix-like systems.  If you were suitably motivated, you could fetch the source code and try to port it.